# Adding ID's to mySQL DB and DB knows which f_name and l_name to use

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

I have an ID taken from a JAVA program and add it to my database over JDBC, the database logs the timestamp of everytime the ID gets sent to the database.

All the jave program send to the mySQL DB is the unique ID for the particular card. My database looks like this

```
--------------------------------------------
|id         | f_name   | l_name | timeStamp|
+-----------+----------+--------+----------+
|22 00 33   | peter    | bobs   |2015-07-10|
|19 88 E7   | greg     | drip   |2015-07-10|
```

and so on, initially the database is created with all f_name, l_name and the ID, but then when i update from my java program and pass just the ID (which is all the information the program knows due to the ID coming from an RFID tag) it gives me null values across the names.

```
--------------------------------------------
|id         | f_name   | l_name | timeStamp|
+-----------+----------+--------+----------+
|22 00 33   | peter    | bobs   |2015-07-10|
|19 88 E7   | greg     | drip   |2015-07-10|
|22 00 33   | NULL     | NULL   |2015-07-10|
|19 88 E7   | NULL     | NULL   |2015-07-10|
```

I realise this is going to happen so my question would be, how do i fix this? so the names appear instead of null? I'm pretty new to DB's and its a wee bit confusing! Should i use triggers? another Table? 
If so any help would be great!!!

Thanks Jonny

Comment: is ID (or should it not be) a primary key? The problematic records have duplicated IDs...

Comment: Hi Marmite, yes i had the ID as a primary key, but then it stops me like you say having duplicate records, and duplicate records are needed because its just the Timestamp im really after.

Comment: `... its just the Timestamp im really after` than create a new table with only ID and timestamp? Anyway please post your SQL statements and formulate the problem.